# How does a function call give a compile-time type?

Tags: c++, syntax, range, standards, c++17

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

template<typename I, typename O>
tagged_pair<tag::in(I), tag::out(O)>
f(I i, O o)
{
    return { i, o };
}

int main()
{
    char buf[8]{};
    f(std::begin(buf), std::end(buf));
}
```

The code uses [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) and can be compiled with `clang`.

However, I cannot understand why the line `tagged_pair<tag::in(I), tag::out(O)>` is legal. `I` is a type, `tag::in(I)` is also a type, and `tag::in` is not a macro, how does `tag::in(I)` give a type at compile-time?

See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/algorithm/copy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a type of a function accepting `I` and returning `tag::in`, which is also a type.

This is used, for example in [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), like `std::function<void(int)>`.